# Highcharts hide categories that don't fit

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible in Highcharts to hide categories when they don't fit? I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require me to explicitly specify which labels to hide.

For example, in [the following chart](http://jsfiddle.net/dNyXU/), `"Feb"`, `"Apr"`, `"Jun"`, `"Aug"`, `"Oct"` and `"Dec"` would be hidden.

[image]

Comment: In which circumstances categoreis doesnt fit? You mean that i.e have data1, and categories should be but if you use data2 categoreis should be? You can control labels by label formatter.

Comment: Whoops. Sorry, I forgot to save my JSFiddle changes. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require me to explicitly specify which labels to hide." - No, it is not possible. Highchart will not hide the x-axis label until you tell it to do s0. Check this

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/labels-staggerlines/

```
staggerLines: 1
```

change staggerlines to get this

http://jsfiddle.net/QsvUT/

```
staggerLines: 2
```

and step it to get this

http://jsfiddle.net/QsvUT/1/

```
step: 2
```

Check your chart size and play with these options. Highchart won't hide it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass catagories as a json from your server side and replace with the catagories array you have

```
categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
```

that will solve your problem .

```
 categories: {catagories_json}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Can you give an example of the JSON I need to pass in to the categories object? The categories themselves can't be changed in my application. The JSFiddle I provided is just an example.

Comment: when your question is not perfect how can you down vote my answer .First of all your question is not even complete . My answer is a general answer for your question . If you don't tell me why your catagory cannot be changed how can i know .

Comment: I downvoted your answer because it didn't answer my question. If I follow your answer, (i.e. replace the categories array with an object, I wouldn't be any closer to a working solution. I did make a mistake when writing my question, which was my fault, but if the question didn't make sense then it would have been better if you had commented and told me so.